# Why doesn't stopImmediatePropagation work in this fiddle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, stoppropagation

I am trying to prevent another event from occurring by using `stopImmediatePropagation()`. The event is tied to the same element I am using to bind to `stopImmediatePropagation()`.

The scenario is that I am using a library (`tour.js`) for a web tour. During the web tour I do not want any interaction with the page to be possible (except for the clicking on the next/back button for the tour).

The way that I am achieving this is by using `stopImmediatePropagation()` on the elements that have on clicks binded to them. I then unbind the `stopImmediatePropagation` when the tour is exited.

This has worked so far when the action I am trying to prevent is called through the jquery `click()` method, but it does not seem to work when the action is binded through the `on()` method

I am having an issue where I am calling `stopImmediatePropagation()`, yet the other actions still run. I have created an example in a simple JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/0w74vkmj/

HTML:

```
<button id="button">Hi</button>
```

JS:

```
$("#button").on("click", function(){
    alert("hi");
});

$("#button").on("click", function(e){
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```

Comment: Here is the doc https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopImmediatePropagation it tells you why in the starting Note part

Comment: I missed that. I couldn't find any mention of that behavior in the jquery docs: https://api.jquery.com/event.stopimmediatepropagation/

Answer (score 0):

Since the 'hi' is being added first, it's being fired first. Changing it to this works as you expect it to:

```
$("#button").on("click", function(e){
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});

$("#button").on("click", function(){
    alert("hi");
});
```